# How to merge two strings alternatively in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, merge

given input str1 is "abc" and str2 is "def" output should be adbecf
and given str1 = "ab" and str2 = "def" output should be adbef

my output has been:

merge('abc','def')
"adbecfNaN"

merge('ab','def')
"adbeundefinedf"

I have been attempting to filter undefined and NAN, but it's not working.

Here's my code:

```
function merge (str1, str2) {

  var a = str1.split("").filter(Boolean);

  var b = str2.split("");

  var mergedString = '';


  for(var i = 0; i <= a.length && i <= b.length; i++) {

       mergedString +=  a[i] + b[i];

    }

    return mergedString;

}
```

Comment: `a[i]` is `undefined` when `i == a.length`; you want `i < a.length` instead of `<=`.

Comment: I tried that suggestion and my output was merge('ab','def')
"adbe." I'm still missing the "f".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use `<` and not `<=` in loop condition since array indexes are started from 0. That is why you are getting NaN. you can do something like this:

```js
function merge (str1, str2) {

  var a = str1.split("").filter(Boolean);

  var b = str2.split("");

  var mergedString = '';


  for(var i = 0; i < a.length || i < b.length; i++) {  //loop condition checks if i is less than a.length or b.length
   if(i < a.length)  //if i is less than a.length add a[i] to string first.
     mergedString +=  a[i];
   if(i < b.length)  //if i is less than b.length add b[i] to string.
     mergedString +=  b[i];
  }
return mergedString;

}
console.log(merge('abc','def'));
console.log(merge('ab','def'));
```

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way and probably the fastest, is to iterate the smallest length of the string and then take the rest of both string.

```js
function zip(a, b) {
    var i,
        l = Math.min(a.length, b.length),
        temp = '';

    for( i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        temp += a[i] + b[i];
    }
    return temp + a.slice(i) + b.slice(i);
}

console.log(zip('abc', '123')); // a1b2c3
console.log(zip('ab', '123'));  // a1b23
console.log(zip('abcd', '12')); // a1b2cd
```

With ES6, you could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with the built in mapper for the letters.

```js
var a = "ab",
    b = "def",
    result = Array.from(a.length > b.length ? a : b, (_, i) => (a[i] || "") + (b[i] || ""))
                  .join('');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach: Iterate over the longest string, output the combination of the characters at the current index, use the empty string if no character exists at the current index.

```js
console.log(merge('ab','def'));

function merge(a, b){
  for(var i = 0, s = '', l = Math.max(a.length, b.length); i < l; i++){
    s += a.charAt(i) || '';
    s += b.charAt(i) || '';
  }
  return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const merge = (str1, str2) => str1.length && `${str1[0]}${merge(str2, str1.slice(1))}` || str2;

console.log(merge('abc','def'));
console.log(merge('ab','def'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the effect of the [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) tag function here:

```js
var a = "abc", b = "DEF";
var result = String.raw({ raw: a }, ...b) + b.substring(a.length - 1);
console.log(result);
```

This `raw` property is expected to be an iterable that provides the raw strings that surround interpolated values which are provided by the other arguments (`...b`). As a string is iterable (yielding its characters) the intended alteration is achieved.

If `b` has fewer characters than `a`, then the interpolated values are assumed empty (which is desired here). When `b` has as many or more characters, then the remaining characters must be concatenated explicitly. We use `substring` here instead of the also popular `slice`, as it will treat a negative argument as 0, which is desired here.

Answer (score 0):

JS bin link -https://jsbin.com/nihoxivoxa/edit?js,console

```js
function merge (str1, str2) {

  var a = str1.split("");

  var b = str2.split("");
  
  var count = 0;
  
  var merged_string = "";
  //let's determine the loop counts, which depends on the smaller length of string
  
  a.length < b.length ? count = a.length: count = b.length;
  
  
  for( var i=0; i< count; i++){
    merged_string += a[i]+b[i];
    
  }
  
  // add remaining characters

    count < str1.length 
    ? merged_string += str1.substr(count, str1.length)
    : merged_string += str2.substr(count, str2.length)

  
  return merged_string;

 
}
console.log(merge('ab','xysfergtrhyhn'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function merge(s1, s2) {
  var result = "";
  for(var i=0; i<s1.length && i<s2.length; i++){
   result+=s1[i]+s2[i];
  }
 s1.length<s2.length?result+=s2.substr(s1.length):result+=s1.substr(s2.length)
 return result;
}
console.log(merge("abc","12345"));
console.log(merge("12345","abc"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the strings to arrays, you can recursively shift the first element off of each array onto a new array, then continue until there are no elements left in both arrays, finally returning the new array.

```js
const shift = (a, b) => a.length||b.length?[a.shift(), b.shift(), ...shift(a,b)]:[];

console.log(shift([...'acegik'],[...'bdfhjl']).join('')); // abcdefghijkl
console.log(shift([...'aceg'  ],[...'bdfhjl']).join('')); // abcdefghjl
console.log(shift([...'acegik'],[...'bdfh'  ]).join('')); // abcdefghik
```

Answer (score 0):

With Lodash in ES6, it is possible to solve this problem in one line code:

```
_.zip('abc'.split(''), 'def'.split('')).reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr.join(''), '');
```

Here, [`zip`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#zip) function is provided by a node library called `Lodash`, which can be installed from npm: https://lodash.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small function that will break down two strings to produce an array of characters in the same alternating sequence you described. You can then use `join('')` to combine these characters into one string.

```js
var m = (a, b) => a.length ? [a[0], ...m(b, a.slice(1))] : b;
var string1 = "SCE ESG!";
var string2 = "ERTMSAE";
var mix = m(string1, string2);

console.log(mix.join(''));
```

or if you need it to work for any number of input strings:

```js
    var m = (a = [], ...b) => 
        b.length ? a.length ? [a[0], ...m(...b, a.slice(1))] : m(...b) : a;
    var string1 = "SR SG";
    var string2 = "EEMSE";
    var string3 = "CTEA!";
    var mix = m(string1, string2, string3);

    console.log(mix.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
let b = "1234567890";

const mix1 = [...a].map((a, i) => b[i] ? `${a}${b[i]}` : a).join('');
const mix2 = [...a].reduce((p, c, i) => b[i] ? `${p}${c}${b[i]}` : `${p}${c}`, "");
console.log("MIX: ", '\n', mix1, '\n', mix2);
```

Hope you guys are here with me, *I'm trying to answer this over* **ES6**

You can achieve the answer using any one mixing listed above.
I've used, **.map** and **.reduce**

Answer (score 0):

```js
const b = "123456 e";
const a = "123456 12345hello";
let res = "";
let len = a.length > b.length ?  a.length:  b.length;

for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  res +=( !a[i] || !b[i]) ? (a[i] ??= b[i]) : a[i] + b[i];
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

we can use a while loop inside a function who return the result of the iteration of the two words index by index..

```js
const mergeAlternately = function(word1, word2) {
  let merged = "";
  let i = 0;
  let j = 0;
  while (i < word1.length || j < word2.length) {
    if (i < word1.length) {
      merged += word1[i];
      i++;
    }
    if (j < word2.length) {
      merged += word2[j];
      j++;
    }
  }
  return merged;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

How about simply use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)?

```js
const s1 = "abc", s2 = "DEF";
const nwStr = [...s1]
  .reduce( (acc, val, i) => acc.conact(val + s2[i]), `` );
console.log(nwStr);
```